Does the $C^*$-algebra $ C_{r}^* (G) $ contain projections?
Let $A$ be a $C^*$ - algebra.

Definition,

Let $p \in A$.
$p$ is a projection if and only if, $ p^* = p $ and $ p^2 = p $.
===========================
Let $G$ be a topological group which is locally compact, Hausdorff and second countable.
Let $ C_{r}^* (G) $ be the reduced $C^*$-algebra of $G$.

Question,

Does the $C^*$-algebra $ C_{r}^* (G) $ contain always projections as defined above ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

There is always the trivial projection $p=0$ and for discrete groups also $p=1$. But $C_r^\ast(G)$ may contain no projections expect for $0$ and $1$. For example, this is the case for $G=\mathbb Z^n$. In this case, $C_r^\ast(G)\cong C_0(\hat G)=C(\mathbb T^n)$, where $\mathbb T^n$ is the $n$-dimensional torus. The projections in $C(X)$ for $X$ compact are exactly the characteristic functions of clopen subsets of $X$, and $\mathbb T^n$ is connected, which means there are no clopen subsets expect for $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb T^n$. In fact, it is a conjecture of Kadison (sometimes also attributed to Kaplansky) that $C_r^\ast(G)$ never contains any non-trivial projections if $G$ is a torsion-free discrete group.

It's worth noting for people new to this stuff that any torsion element $g \in G$ yields the projection $p_g := \frac{1}{\lvert g \rvert}\sum_{k=0}^{\lvert g \rvert - 1} g^k$ in the group algebra $\mathbf{C}[G]$, where $\lvert g \rvert$ is the order of $g$ in $G$. This is why Kadison–Kaplansky is a conjecture about torsion-free groups.

To complement MaoWao's answer with a non-commutative example, a famous case of projectionless $C_r(G)$ is the case $G=\mathbb F_n$, the free group on $n$ generators. This was shown by Pimsner-Voiculescu. Other proofs were given by Cuntz and by Haagerup-Schultz-Thorbjørnsen.
